# IIS rewrites .html URL to ColdFusion - how do I get a query string?

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion, url-rewriting

I'm taking over a ColdFusion application and I'm having some trouble with the rewrites.

The site is on an IIS7/CF9.0.1/SQL Server stack.  Helicon manager is handling the rewrites.

Most of the URLs are written to an html file, so we'd have something like /profile.html

The URL gets rewritten by this line:

```
RewriteRule /([^\?]*?)\.(html)(\??)(.*)? /default.cfm?name=$1.$2&$4 [I]
```

The problem occurs when there's a query string like /view.html?id=123.  The query string *should* be written by the $4 variable, but I'm never getting anything in the application, when I dump the URL like so:

```
<cfset objRequest = GetPageContext().GetRequest() />
<cfset strUrl = objRequest.GetRequestUrl().Append(
"?" & objRequest.GetQueryString()
 ).ToString()
 />
<cfoutput>#strUrl#</cfoutput>
```

I get something like: http://10.211.55.6/default.cfm?name=view.html&.  The query string never shows up.

I believe it's an IIS setting - allowing the .html handler access to GET variables maybe?  I've set up an .html handler, but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because RewriteRule never sees the query string, only the path of the resource. To access the query string you need to use a Rewrite Condition

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}            ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.html$           default.cfm?name=$1.html&%1 [NC,L]
```

In this example we are just examining the query string and using `%1` which means the first group from the `RewriteCond` this is overkill in your example where you don't need to match anything so you could do it like this:-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.html$           default.cfm?name=$1.html&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

However, the smart way is just to use the correct flag to do what you want to do which is `QSA` which means query string append like so:-

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)\.html$           default.cfm?name=$1.html [NC,QSA,L]
```

All the docs for Helicon's ISAPI rewrite can be found here: http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/.  They're quite handy to bookmark.

I hope that helps.